# Use Yii2 inside Sailsjs

Tags: javascript, yii2, sails.js, frontend, backend

I have a problem in my web project
I create one website with **sails.js** and I need to create administrator panel for manage website I created with sails.js. This is very hard for me because I'm beginner in sails.js
I think if use **Yii2 Advanced framework** for *backend* and use **sails.js** for *frontend* it's good idea but I don't know how to use sails.js inside Yii2 and work correctly.

Excuse me for my English language.

Comment: Sails.js is already server side. By client side, I mean code that is executed in browser

Comment: This is somehow the next level of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) question.